# For a given string, develop a prolog load (aSCii_Encoded (S, X))

Tags: prolog

hei there i have exams today on Logic programing with Prolog language
is there anyone that can help me here some of my questions

Question 1:

- For a given string, develop a prolog load (aSCii_Encoded (S, X)) which calculates the following function, where s represents the function value of the string X received from the user. You can use as many auxiliary and ready-to-load as you want

Hint- It is the sum of the ASCII value of the character in the string and the values obtained by the string in the string.

Let the example string S be abc

x function value is calculated as below
ASCII value for the character a: 97 sequence in string 1 value = 1x97 = 97
b: character ASCII value 98 sequence in string 2 value = 1x98 = 196
ASCII value for the
c: character is the order of 99 strings 3 value = 3x99 = 297

X is equal to the sum of this value x = 97 + 196 + 297 = 590

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. **Please also note that [so] is not a coding service where you can throw your homework and wait for others to do it for you**. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `atom_codes` predicate to get the list of character codes:

```
?- atom_codes(abc, Codes).
Codes = [97, 98, 99].
```

Then do your arithmetic on the resulting list.